# Converting an equiangular cubemap to an equirectangular one

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, projection, skybox

I am making a retro-style game with OpenGL, and I want to draw my own cubemaps for it. Here is an example of one:

[image]

As you can tell, there is no perspective warping anywhere; each face is fully equiangular. When using this as a cubemap, the result is this:

[image]

As you can see, it looks box-y, and not spherical at all. I know of a solution to this, which is to remap each point on the cubemap to a a sphere position. I have done this manually by creating a sphere mesh and mapping the cubemap texture onto it (and then rendering that to an environment map), but this is time-consuming and complicated.

I seek a different solution: in my fragment shader, I hope to remap the sampling ray to a sphere position, instead of a cube position. Here is my original fragment shader, without any changes:

```c
#version 400 core

in vec3 cube_edge;

out vec3 color;

uniform samplerCube skybox_sampler;

void main(void) {
    color = texture(skybox_sampler, cube_edge).rgb;
}
```

I can get a ray that maps to the sphere by just normalizing `cube_edge`, but that doesn't change anything, for some reason. After messing around a bit, I tried this mapping, which almost works, but not quite:

```c
vec3 sphere_edge = vec3(cube_edge.x, normalize(cube_edge).y, cube_edge.z);
```

[image]

As you can see, some faces become spherical in nature, whereas the top face warps inwards, instead of outwards.

I also tried the results from this site: http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html, but the faces were not curved outwards enough.

I have been stuck on this for so long now - if you know how I can change my cube to sphere mapping in my fragment shader, or if that's even possible, please let me know!

Comment: It sounds like you want a cylindrical projection for the four faces along the horizon, but it's in conflict with the top and bottom faces. So I'd say that no projection would leave you satisfied.

Comment: At the same time you say that you somehow mapped it to a sphere mesh and got satisfactory results. I highly doubt that. But if you're still convinced that it looked good, you should instead include that code and the results you got, and ask how to do it per-fragment instead.

Comment: @Yakov Galka That code is a couple hundred lines, so I didn't include it here. The results essentially looked like each cube face pushed slightly outwards (like each face on a sphere), with some overlap between the original cubemap faces. It worked, but it's complicated to do, and the output texture must have a much, much greater resolution in order to avoid jagged edges on my pixel art skybox (which is unsatisfactory). Therefore, doing the remapping in my normal cubemap fragment shader seems ideal.

Comment: @YakovGalka I am fine with some spherical perspective warping, as long as I can remove the jagged boxy edges.

Comment: @YakovGalka Upon further examination, it seems like the method that I thought worked wasn't working exactly as it should. Here's basically the steps: 1. Make a single subdivided face of a unit cube. 2. Draw 6 instances of it, with each instance rotated make a unit cube, and each position normalized to map it to a unit sphere. 3. Use geometry shader instancing too, in order to draw to 6 cubemap faces. 4. In the fragment shader, use the position on the sphere to sample from the original cubemap. This makes no difference for for (0, 0, 0), but for lower y's, it works okay (excluding corners).

Comment: @YakovGalka I've seen the Google EAC thing before, but I never had any success with implementing it, since I couldn't find a proper mapping from a cube to a sphere (which is what I need).

Comment: @YakovGalka Yes - I will mess around with that and try something out. I think the tricky thing there is, given the original cubemap ray, finding out the 2d UV of that given face, doing the remapping via arctan there, and then getting a cubemap ray back from that again. Hmm...

Comment: @YakovGalka I tried it out; almost no difference (I remapped the xy-components of gl_Position when using the detailed method in the 4-step process I detailed above). See here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n5lfdmtw5w, almost no difference for each remapped component.

Comment: @YakovGalka Note that I was doing the remapping at eye level (there, how a cube and sphere look is exactly the same; the remapping only made a tiny difference).

Comment: Btw -- if you're standing on the ground of a sufficiently large planet, the horizon will split your environment map exactly in the half. You, on the other hand, had drawn it too low, which is one contributing factor why this looks weird.

Comment: @YakovGalka Huh, I had my eye level at `y = 0`, I think (`y` is up for me); are you basing that just on how the screenshot in my post looks?

Comment: I'm basing it on your cubemap texture

Comment: @YakovGalka Aha - yes i had shifted y slightly down - defined by some percentage towards the box top. That was more useful before for various reasons, but not anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you can tell, there is no perspective warping anywhere; each face is fully equiangular.

This premise is incorrect. You hand-drew some images; this doesn't make them equiangular.

'Equiangular cubemap' (EAC) specifically means a cubemap remapped [by this formula](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jill-Boyce/publication/326504559_JVET-H1004_Algorithm_descriptions_of_projection_format_conversion_and_video_quality_metrics_in_360Lib/links/5b513e410f7e9b240ff09c45/JVET-H1004-Algorithm-descriptions-of-projection-format-conversion-and-video-quality-metrics-in-360Lib.pdf) (section 2.4):

```
u = 4/pi * atan(u)
v = 4/pi * atan(v)
```

Let's recognize first that the term is misleading, because even though EAC aims at reducing the variation in sampling rate, the sampling rate is not constant. In fact no 2d projection of any part of a sphere can truly be equi-angular; this is a mathematical fact.

Nonetheless, we can try to apply this correction. Implemented in GLSL fragment shader as:

```
d /= max(abs(d.x), max(abs(d.y), abs(d.z));
d = atan(d)/atan(1);
```

gives the following result:

[image: EAC]
[image: EAC]

Compare it with the uncorrected `d`:

[image: uncorrected]
[image: uncorrected]

As you can see the EAC projection shrinks the pixels in the middle by a little bit, and expands them near the corners, so that they cover more equal area. However, EAC is not a smooth mapping near the edges of the cube -- i.e. it can make straight lines pointy -- which seems like the artifact you want to avoid.

Instead, it appears that you want a cylindrical projection around the horizon, which is smooth. It can be implemented like so:

```
d /= length(d.xy);
d.xy /= max(abs(d.x), abs(d.y));
d.xy = atan(d.xy)/atan(1);
```

And it gives the following result:

[image: cylindrical]
[image: cylindrical]

However there's no artifact-free way to fit the top/bottom square faces of the cube onto the circular faces of the cylinder -- which is why you see the artifacts there.

Bottom-line: you cannot fit the image that you drew onto a sphere in a visually pleasing way. You should instead re-focus your effort on alternative ways of authoring your environment map. I recommend you try using an [equidistant cylindrical projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) for the horizon, cap it with solid colors above/below a fixed latitude, and use billboards for objects that cannot be represented in that projection.

For example, using the following 2D texture:

[image: cylindrical]

And the following formula:

```
float tau = 6.283185;
float u = atan(d.y, d.x);
float v = atan(d.z, length(d.xy));
OUT = texture(TEX, vec2(u/tau, 2*v/tau + 0.5));
```

I can get these results:

[image: cylindrical]
[image: cylindrical]

I think this will get you further than any cubemap based tweaks.

Comment: This is awesome! I will figure out a way to render the caps. Also - in your example code - I found that it only worked when I changed the components operated upon from `.xy` to `.xz` - not sure if that's an issue on your or my end.

Comment: @CaspianAhlberg I use z-up, you probably use y-up.

Comment: is there really no way that I can render the top/bottom caps using my current artwork? I am fine with a little distortion - or perhaps there is a way to keep a majority of the top/bottom caps, while discarding some texture details?

Comment: @CaspianAhlberg for the millionth time, no. cubemap is not what you need here. See my edit with what you can get without a cubemap.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the size of the geometry on which the environment is placed is too small. You are not looking at the environment but at the inside of a small cube in which you are sitting. The environment map should behave as if you are always in the center of the map and the environment is infinitely far away. I suggest to draw the environment map on the far plane of the viewing frustum. You can do this by setting the z-component of the clip space position equal to the w-component in the vertex shader. If you set `z` to `w`, you guarantee that the final `z` value of the position will be 1.0. This is the `z` value of the far plane. (You can do that with [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) `gl_Position = clipPos.xyww`). It is quite sufficient to draw a cube and wrap the environment by looking up the map with the interpolated vertices of the cube. In the case of a `samplerCube`, the 3-dimensional texture coordinate is treated as a direction vector. You can use the vertex coordinate of the cube to look up the texture.

Vertex shader:

```c
cube_edge = inVertex.xyz;

vec4 clipPos = projection * view * vec4(inVertex.xyz, 1.0);
gl_Position = clipPos.xyww;
```

Fragment shader:

```c
color = texture(skybox_sampler, cube_edge).rgb;
```

The solution is also explained in detail at [LearnOpenGL - Cubemap](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps).

Comment: Yes, I am already doing this. I forgot to show my vertex shader code! The cube stays static when I move, as you describe. This does not address the boxiness of my cubemap though.

Comment: Not sure if I made this clear - my problem is that I am making cubemaps by hand, and I want to apply some mapping to them in order to make them look like a sphere (not a cube!) when rendered.

Comment: @CaspianAhlberg Yes I know that is exactly what I've answered. See also [LearnOpenGL - Cubemaps](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps). (By the way, the code in the answer is tested and works). Did you even try it? The solution is `clipPos.xyww`

Comment: Yes, that tutorial is one that I used to develop the cubemap code in my game. I have that exact code with `.xyww` there; that is not relevant to my question. To rephrase my question, I am asking how to convert an equiangular cubemap to an equirectangular one (since the ones I am drawing are equiangular). See here https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/3Sfbbc/ for an image display ing the difference; essentially, there is no spherical distortion in the cubemaps I draw, and I wish to apply that to those. The `.xyww` code has no bearing on that.